# Why doesn't css selector - 'begins with' allow double-dash at end?

Tags: css, css-selectors, bem

In writing CSS I use BEM methodology and I've found using the CSS selector 'begins with' - `[class^="classname"]` very useful. This is especially true when declaring styles for modifiers, i.e. `.block__element--modifier`.

Therefore when writing CSS rules I would like to use `[class^="block__element--"]` to target specific elements regardless of their modifier. However, I've noticed the double-dash at the end of the selector fails to target the elements. A single dash however will work.

I've had a look through the [CSS Selectors Level 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) but cannot see any mention of why the double-dash would fail.

Comment: What does your markup look like? Remember that attribute selectors consider the entire attribute value, even if you are querying the `class` attribute.

Comment: As comments show, the issue was a problem that was not described in the question at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that should cause you any problem as I just tested with the markup below and it works well...

```
<div class="block__element--modifier">Hello</div>

div[class^="block__element--"] {
    color: red;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cTwSv/4/)</kbd>

Also, this `^=` means that the `class` name begins with the above string, failing that will result in failure of your selector as well, you may like to use `*=` instead which searches for a substring.

So if you have a `class` declared before say like

```
<div class="hello block__element--modifier">Hello</div>
```

Will fail your selector <kbd><s>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcTfG/)</s></kbd>, so in this case you may like using

```
div[class*="block__element--"] {
    color: red;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcTfG/1/)</kbd>

Comment: @BoltClock LOL, total disaster... I am probably sleepy.. thanks for the comment, will edit...

Comment: It seems a parent with the class (like) `block__element-group` had priority and was throwing me off when using just the single dash. Thanks for the clarification.